# Compare two tables with same row type PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, select

I have two temporary tables of the same row type:

```
items
id - BIGINT
value - float
```

The two temp tables: called A and B have:

```
40 items in Table A
150 items in Table B
```

I want to compare every item in Table A with every item in Table B and return all items in which:

```
(a.value - b.value < 5)
```

into a third temporary table called Table C.

I can do this easily with loops, but I know loops are fairly slow, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it just with select statements.

Comment: `... and return all items ...` Please define `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
insert into c
select * from a
where exists (select 1 from b where a.value - b.value < 5);
```

Or do you also want all values from table B?

In that case,

```
insert into c
select * from a
where exists (select 1 from b where a.value - b.value < 5)
union
select * from b
where exists (select 1 from a where a.value - b.value < 5);
```